# Unit parameter in pymodbus custom request

Tags: pymodbus

this is my firt post here.
I was lurking for a while.

So, I'm having problem regarding custom message in pymodbus ModbusTcpClient

I'm playing with one old Modbus device which has custom registers and commands.
I am able to read/write coils, registers, etc.
Problem is that this device needs special command for some sort of reset.

I made some wireshark sniffing and I made custom message, but I'm stuck in defining unit parameter.

here is code snippet:

```
class CustomModbusRequest(ModbusRequest):
    function_code = 8

    def __init__(self, address):
        ModbusRequest.__init__(self)
        self.address = address
        self.count = 1

    def encode(self):
        return struct.pack('>HH', self.address, self.count)

    def decode(self, data):
        self.address, self.count = struct.unpack('>HH', data)

    def execute(self, context):
        if not (1 <= self.count <= 0x7d0):
            return self.doException(ModbusExceptions.IllegalValue)
        if not context.validate(self.function_code, self.address, self.count):
            return self.doException(ModbusExceptions.IllegalAddress)
        values = context.getValues(self.function_code, self.address,
                               self.count)
        return CustomModbusResponse(values)

def custom_8():
    client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.0.222')
    connection = client.connect()
    request = CustomModbusRequest(170)
    result = client.execute(request)
    print(result)
    time.sleep(1)
```

In normal request for read register there is specified unit parameter, like this:

```
    request = client.read_input_registers(513,4, unit=0x4)
```

In custom request, I don't know how to specify this. In wireshark I can see that in custom message, I'm sending request to address 0, and I need to use address 4.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass the `unit` to custom message and that should do the trick.
`request = CustomModbusRequest(170, unit=<unit_id>)`. You also will have to update the `__init__` of `CustomModbusRequest` to pass additional kwargs to `parent`.

```
class CustomModbusRequest(ModbusRequest):
    function_code = 8

    def __init__(self, address, **kwargs):
        ModbusRequest.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.address = address
        self.count = 1


...
...

request = CustomModbusRequest(170, unit=<unit_id>)
result = client.execute(request)
```